# Generate a report that shows the percentage of users that did not log in again 7 days after the initial login

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to generate a report that shows the percentage of users that did not log in again 7 days after the initial login. Currently I am able to write a SQL script that shows the number of unique users that logged in between 1st jan 2017 till 1st feb 2017. But How do I find the number of users who did not log in again after 7 days? Thanks

```
select
  count ( distinct a.user_id) as unique_user_ids_logins_in_month,
  to_char(first_hit_at::date,'dd-mm-yyyy') as date
from
  stg_marketing.ga_sessions a
where
  a.first_hit_at >('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000')
  and a.first_hit_at <('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000')
  and user_login_state = 'true' 
  and last_hit_at::date > first_hit_at::date 
group by 2
order by 2 asc


 Unique_user_logins    Date
  97                 01-01-2017
  96                 02-01-2017
  62                 03-01-2017
  61                 04-01-2017
  69                 05-01-2017
  65                 06-01-2017
  75                 07-01-2017
  82                 08-01-2017
```

Comment: what do you need as output? the number of users who didn't login within 7 days of their initial login? please add the expected output to the question.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Yes, number of users who did not login again in next 7 days. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what output do you exactly need, but this is how you can find unique users, who have only one login, or have more than 7 days between first and second logins:

```
with  t(user_id, login_dt) as(
    select 1, '2017-01-01 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 1, '2017-01-05 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 2, '2017-01-01 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 2, '2017-01-09 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 3, '2017-01-01 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 3, '2017-01-05 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 4, '2017-01-01 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 4, '2017-01-10 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 4, '2017-01-11 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 22, '2017-01-10 02:00:00'::timestamp union all
    select 22, '2017-01-10 02:00:04'::timestamp  

)


select user_id  from (
    select user_id, login_dt::date, row_number() over(partition by user_id  order by login_dt) as rn
    from t
    where
    login_dt >= '2017-01-01' and login_dt < '2017-02-01'
) t
where
rn < 3
group by user_id
having
count(login_dt) = 1
or
min(login_dt) + 7 < max(login_dt)
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/RKEHTZ93773

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. How can I change the logic in case if I need to see who did log in in the next 7 days? Thanks for the input.